# How to deal with Exim ***Frozen***?

Tags: email-server, exim, email-bounces

When i checked mail queue, i have found lots-of Frozen mail entries in exim mail queue, will it effect my mail server to deliver mail? Is it possible mail delayed because of frozen ?
Entries in queue like this

7h  2.0K 1V4Qlq-000H4P-M4 <> *****frozen ***
              emailid@mail.com

Answer (score 2):

Messages are frozen when the mail server has determined it cannot do anything to deliver the message. (they can also be manually frozen).

Exim has option to set how long frozen messages are kept on the system.

On a Debian/Ubuntu based install the `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options` file has the option `timeout_frozen_after = 7d`.  Which means messages frozen for 7 days will get expunged.

Frozen messages really shouldn't be a problem on most systems.  They are often just spam messages that can't get properly delivered.

Comment: there is no directory name /etc/exim4 .... i am using centos.